# os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM EXCEL.exe') in python

Tags: python, xls

I am using `os.startfile(excel file)` to open excel application. After running `task kill`, when I try to open excel again it gives me recovery options.

Is there any way to open the excel application and close it properly without giving recovery option when I open it again?

Comment: You can use COM: https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html

Comment: maybe try os.system('TASKKILL /T /IM EXCEL.exe')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the argument /F you force kill the program, not giving it time to save things or clear memory etc.
what `os.system('taskkill /T /IM EXCEL.exe)` does is it sends the same singnal as the program gets when you press the close program button

Comment: Do we have a way to terminate only file which is opened due to subprocess.Popen(excel_file,shell=True) call? i tried p=subprocess.Popen(excel_file,shell=True) p.kill() and p.terminate() but my excel file is not closing

Comment: Would like to know if you have found a way..
TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Microsoft Excel - myFile.xlsx"
does not work..